# How do I link up into a "parent" folder from the child folder? (child folder ->beverages/elixir.html) (parent folder ->lounge.html)

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, parent-child, parent

```
<head>
    <title>Head First Lounge</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Welcome to the New and Improved Head First Lounge</h1>

        <img src="images/drinks.gif">

        <p>
            Join us any evening for refreshing <a href="beverage/elixir.html">elixirs</a>, 
            and maybe a game or two of <em>Dance Dance Revolution</em>. Wireless
            access is always provided; BYOWS (Bring your own web server).
        </p>

    <h2>Directions</h2>

        <p> 
            You'll find us right in the center of downtown Webville. If you need help
            finding us, check out our <a href="about/directions.html">detailed directions</a> 
            . Come join us!

        </p>

</body>
```

Trying to link the parent and child...and I could not figure how the links works.

Comment: can u add more detail to the question?

Comment: beverage/ or beverages/?

Comment: Nemo - it is beverage.

Comment: Tejus - I create an href to represent the path to traced to the parent (<a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a>). But I had to create another folder in the original folder to do the link for the child to link to to the parent. It worked, but the images are broken...How do I fix that? :( Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When **hosting** the site you can just put the file into one folder and you will be able to link it with just the name of te **file** so thisisatest.html for example.

Comment: I create an href to represent the path to traced to the parent (<a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a>). But I had to create another folder in the original folder to do the link for the child to link to to the parent. It worked, but the images are broken...How do I fix that? :( Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
../xy
```

to get into the parent folder

Comment: I create an href to represent the path to traced to the parent (<a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a>). But I had to create another folder in the original folder to do the link for the child to link to to the parent. It worked, but the images are broken...How do I fix that? :( Thank you.

Comment: The link should be completely independent of the images. So if your images are broken, does that mean, that they are distorted or that the image file is broken. But then you are not able to view the image at all...